# pdf file download

Tags: actionscript-3

Once a member signs up a form they can download the pdf file. Currently, the pdf file is link with HTML which means that anyone with the url can download it. 
What's the best way to encrypt a page so that the user don't see the url to a pdf file.
I tried creating a flash file and link the URL from flash using the following:

```
var myPDF = new URLRequest("temp/test.pdf");
navigateToURL(myPDF);
```

but it opens a new window and show's the URL !!! is there a way to make the browse forcefully download the file instead of opening in on a new browser.

Thanks,
Rex

Answer (score 0):

Use can use authentication - and until you give the client the cookie (means it is authenticated) he can't access the page.

Comment: Thank you the solution but... once the user authenticates and gets the link to pdf, the user can send the direct URL in email and anyone with the direct URL to pdf can access it. that's what I don't want to happen.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [FileReference.download()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download%28%29).
It will use the OS save dialog to save the file directly to the file system.
It's still not really *secure* but it will not expose the URL directly in the browser window.

It would look something like this:

```
protected var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();

// add event listeners
fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onDownloadProgress);
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDownloadComplete);
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, onFileOpen);
fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
fileRef.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);

// start the download
fileRef.download(new URLRequest("temp/test.pdf"), "Test.pdf");
```